# Ag-grid drag and drop from the toolbar to the grid feature missing in the versions 22nd onwards

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have been using ag-grid-enterprise and have noticed that the feature of dragging and dropping columns from the toolbar into the ag-grid. This feature was there up to version 21.

Is there a way I can enable this feature or this has been removed forever intentionally?

Working version: https://www.ag-grid.com/archive/21.0.0/javascript-grid-tool-panel-component/
[image]

Current version: https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid/tool-panel-columns/
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Seems like they have removed it by default and we can enable it by adding the below flag to the grid definition:

`allowDragFromColumnsToolPanel=true`

```
<ag-grid-angular
  #agGrid
  style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
  id="myGrid"
  class="ag-theme-alpine"
  allowDragFromColumnsToolPanel=true
  [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
  [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
  [sideBar]="sideBar"
  [rowData]="rowData"
  (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
></ag-grid-angular>
```